# Rate of increase for $\int_0^rxf(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $k\geq 1$. Consider a continuous distribution on $(0,1)$ with probability distribution function $f$ and cumulative distribution function $F$, where $f(r)\leq k$ for all $r$. Define for $0<t<1$
$$g(t)=\frac{\int_0^rxf(x)dx}{\int_0^1xf(x)dx},$$
where $0<r<1$ is the value where $F(r)=t$. Clearly, $g(t)$ is an increasing function.

Now, let $f_k,F_k$ denote the functions for the uniform distribution over $[1-\frac1k,1]$, and $g_k$ defined as above for $f_k,F_k$. Is it true that $g(t)\leq g_k(t)$ for all $0<t<1$?

Intuitively it looks like this should be true, because for that particular distribution, $x$ has the highest possible value when $f(x)$ increases. But I'm not quite sure how to prove it.

Comment: In your first formula, the numerator of the RHS should be with a $t$ instead of an $r$.

Comment: @JeanMarie No, $r$ is the value where $F(r)=t$.